# Confluent JDBC Sink Connector Can't recognize record captured by debezium connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I try to cdc postgresql with kafka echo system. The debezium connector captures postgresql 13 data and produce then to kafka. And I attach JDBC sink connector of confluent to other side of kafka, but it does not recognize json message properly.

Tested environment:

- Postgresql 13, WAL logical (docker)
- Debezium 1.9 postgresql connector (pre-built jar)
- confluentinc/kafka-connector-jdbc in github.
- Kafka 2.8
- java 17

Tested table.

create table PERSONS (id integer not null, name varchar(50) not null, nickname varchar(50), primary key(id));

Debezium produced json message on update event. (captured by console-consumer)

```
{

"schema":{
    "type":"struct",
    "fields":[
        {
            "type":"struct",
            "fields":[
                {
                    "type":"int32",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"id"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"name"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":true,
                    "field":"nickname"
                }
            ],
            "optional":true,
            "name":"localdb_postgres.public.persons.Value",
            "field":"before"
        },
        {
            "type":"struct",
            "fields":[
                {
                    "type":"int32",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"id"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"name"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":true,
                    "field":"nickname"
                }
            ],
            "optional":true,
            "name":"localdb_postgres.public.persons.Value",
            "field":"after"
        },
        {
            "type":"struct",
            "fields":[
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"version"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"connector"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"name"
                },
                {
                    "type":"int64",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"ts_ms"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":true,
                    "name":"io.debezium.data.Enum",
                    "version":1,
                    "parameters":{
                        "allowed":"true,last,false,incremental"
                    },
                    "default":"false",
                    "field":"snapshot"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"db"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":true,
                    "field":"sequence"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"schema"
                },
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"table"
                },
                {
                    "type":"int64",
                    "optional":true,
                    "field":"txId"
                },
                {
                    "type":"int64",
                    "optional":true,
                    "field":"lsn"
                },
                {
                    "type":"int64",
                    "optional":true,
                    "field":"xmin"
                }
            ],
            "optional":false,
            "name":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source",
            "field":"source"
        },
        {
            "type":"string",
            "optional":false,
            "field":"op"
        },
        {
            "type":"int64",
            "optional":true,
            "field":"ts_ms"
        },
        {
            "type":"struct",
            "fields":[
                {
                    "type":"string",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"id"
                },
                {
                    "type":"int64",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"total_order"
                },
                {
                    "type":"int64",
                    "optional":false,
                    "field":"data_collection_order"
                }
            ],
            "optional":true,
            "field":"transaction"
        }
    ],
    "optional":false,
    "name":"localdb_postgres.public.persons.Envelope"
},
"payload":{
    "before":null,
    "after":{
        "id":3,
        "name":"Ko Youngrok",
        "nickname":"SuperMen"
    },
    "source":{
        "version":"1.9.2.Final",
        "connector":"postgresql",
        "name":"localdb_postgres",
        "ts_ms":1653878655898,
        "snapshot":"false",
        "db":"postgres",
        "sequence":"[\"23092016\",\"23092304\"]",
        "schema":"public",
        "table":"persons",
        "txId":516,
        "lsn":23092304,
        "xmin":null
    },
    "op":"u",
    "ts_ms":1653878656372,
    "transaction":null
}
```

The error log from Confluent jdbc sink connector.

> [2022-05-30 15:45:26,750] INFO Unable to find fields [SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{INT64}, name='ts_ms', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{localdb_postgres.public.persons.Value:STRUCT}, name='after', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRING}, name='op', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{localdb_postgres.public.persons.Value:STRUCT}, name='before', isPrimaryKey=false}, SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRUCT}, name='transaction', isPrimaryKey=false}] among column names [nickname, id, name] (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure:276)

> [2022-05-30 15:45:26,752] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=conflue-jdbc-sink-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Cannot ALTER TABLE "localdb_postgres"."public"."persons" to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:608)
> io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.TableAlterOrCreateException: Cannot ALTER TABLE "localdb_postgres"."public"."persons" to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value

I suppose,

- Debezium connector intended that purpose of top-level "schema" column is type decription of other top-level column "payload". Every matching columns exist in both schema and payload. Payload column is value and schema column is type description of payload column.
- But confluet connector regards "schema" as table schema, so try to alter table. Of course there's no enouth information to create database column and error was raised.

Any any idea to solve this problem?

This is confluent connector configuration.

```
name=conflue-jdbc-sink-connector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
connection.url=blahblah
connection.user=blahblah
connection.password=blahblah
dialect.name=PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect
insert.mode=insert
pk.mode=none
pk.fields=none
batch.size=3000
delete.enabled=false
topics=localdb_postgres.public.persons
```

Comment: I think you need this https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for comment. But I think debezium generates data according to standards. https://www.confluent.io/ko-kr/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. Look at your data. It has "before" and "after" fields. From what I understand, you are only interested in having the "after" payload written to the Sink database? If so, you need to extract it using a transform (which, yes, only will work on the data that is generated by Debezium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unable to find fields ... source, ts_ms, after, op, before, transaction ...   among column names [nickname, id, name]
```

The JDBC Sink Connect infers only *top level fields* of the records it consumes.

If you want to write only the `after` data payload, for example, you need to [extract it](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html). If you continue to use the JSONConverter, then you will still end up with `schema` and `payload`, but you will only see what's relevant to that data.

E.g. This would be the full record after the transform.

```
    "schema" : {
        "type":"struct",
        "fields":[
            {
                "type":"int32",
                "optional":false,
                "field":"id"
            },
            {
                "type":"string",
                "optional":false,
                "field":"name"
            },
            {
                "type":"string",
                "optional":true,
                "field":"nickname"
            }
        ],
        "name":"localdb_postgres.public.persons.Value"
    }, 
    "payload" : {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Ko Youngrok",
        "nickname":"SuperMen"
    }
```

Comment: The schema that you wrote is very exact. It's jdbc connector wants. And I understand changing event structure is required in my case. But it must be tedious jobs I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "very exact". It's the data that was already in your question.

Comment: "Exact" means elimination of one depth between "schema" and inner "fields". As you said, I mentioned it in my question but I did not showed example itself.